# Memory error when contour plotting in Matlab

Tags: matlab, memory, plot, contour

I run out of memory when I try to plot a contour graph from my data set. In my data file (data.txt), I have three columns of data each specifically for x,y, and z. After learning about contour plotting, I am simply trying to create a mesh of x and y, then assign a value of z to each node in the mesh. My code is as follows:

```
    *clf
dirname_out = '/home/Riyal/Documents/F/Contplot/plot112/';
fignam = 'cont_h.eps';
figure(1);*
load node.txt
x=node(:,2); %set the x-axis data(e.g.-x distance)
y=node(:,1); %set the y-axis data(e.g-time)
z=node(:,3); %set the variable to plot(e.g-velocity)
% x=~isnan(x);
% y=~isnan(y);
% z=~isnan(z);
a=size(node);
b=a(:,1);
xlin=linspace(-4.3862592576,4.9999996647,b);
ylin=linspace(0.0020000001,88.1880041887,b);
%v=[2.4,2.2,2.0,1.8,1.6,1.4,1.2,1.0,0.8,0.6,0.4,0.2,0.16,0.12,0.08,0.04,0.01,0.001,0.0001];
[X,Y]=meshgrid(xlin,ylin);
Z=griddata(x,y,z,X,Y);
mesh(X,Y,Z);
[C,h]=contour(X,Y,Z);
clabel(C,h,'FontSize',10,'Color','b','Rotation',0);
grid on
axis on
xlabel('distance');
ylabel('time');

% ------------------------------
% Information on Figure size
% ------------------------------

set(gcf, 'PaperUnits', 'centimeters');
set(gcf, 'PaperType', 'A4');
%set(gcf, 'PaperOrientation',  'portrait');
 set(gcf, 'PaperOrientation', 'Landscape');

PaperSize = get(gcf,'PaperSize');   % %   Use PaperSize to return the
                                    % %   size of the current paper.%
%width =19.0;
%height = 26.0;

 width = 26.0;                     % % Initialize a variable for width.
 height = 19.0;                    % % Initialize a varible for height.

left = (PaperSize(1)- width)/2;     % % PaperSize (width of paper) for the calculation.
bottom = (PaperSize(2)- height)/2;  % % of PaperSize (height of paper) for the calculation.
myfiguresize = [left, bottom, width, height];   % % Set the figure size and print.
set(gcf, 'PaperPosition', myfiguresize);


% ------------------------------
% Printing to file
% ------------------------------
```

Can anyone let me know why Matlab say the below problem when I have plotted larger data sets than the one I am currently using. I am guessing there is a fault in one of my lines, or there is a better way to get the job done with optimum use of memory? 
Thanks.

```
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

Error in meshgrid (line 59)
        yy = ycol(:,ones(size(xrow)));
```

Comment: What's the dimensions of the variables? Maybe your memory is simply full.

Comment: it depends on the size of your array `node`. You are setting fixed start- and endpoints for your vectors `xlin` and `ylin`, maybe the step size `b` varies among your datasets? One thing you could try is putting `clear node x y z xlin ylin` after the `griddata` line to recover some space if the matrix `node` is really that big.

Comment: Each x,y data column contains nearly 45000 values, and the z is expected to be 45000 x 45000. So yes, it is quite large. But I'm sure there is a way around this problem.

Comment: Thanks Wouter. I tried doing this but it did not make a difference; I received the same error. Any other ideas? I will update here if I find a solution.

Comment: In that case, you'd need about 48 GB of memory to store your data - 16 GB for the `X`,`Y`, and `Z` matrices each (you can check this by typing `A = rand(45000); whos A;`. That won't even run on my machine as I just have 8 GB of RAM). I suggest you reduce your number of samples by using the `decimate` or `downsample` function, then try again. It might still be worthwhile to clear all unneccesary variables to obtain the highest possible resolution if that is what you're after.

Comment: I just have a 16GB, it is not possible to get more than this at the moment. Thank you for the tips on managing memory, I have not used them before. I shall have a go with them and post here what worked/did not work. Thanks again.

Comment: @Riyal Normally it is not worth using that many samples. But if you really need it, there are some ways to save some memory. If your matrix is sparse, it is possible to use a sparse matrix. Each element takes 3 times as much memory as a normal matrix, but all 0 elements will use no memory. I case the matrix is not sparse, there is still possible to half the memory consumption by using single precision instead of double precision. Still, if you want to process all the data on the RAM you must find a way to reduce the number of samples.